# How to make file optional in Oozie workflow?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

Suppose I have a workflow action that I need to get and use a file from hdfs if it exists but not fail otherwise. Is there a way to do this in the workflow configuration?

So, if I have something like this:

```
<action name="run">
    <java>
        <main-class>AJavaProgram</main-class>
        ...
        <arg>-files</arg>
        <arg>properties.json</arg>
        ...
        <file>${concat(additionsPath, "properties.json")}</file>
        ...
    </java>
</action>
```

It works fine so long as that properties file exists in hdfs in the right place, but if it doesn't, the workflow fails. Is there a way to get it to not fail if the file isn't present to be copied from HDFS? A way to make the file optional from the workflow.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Every action has two options

```
<ok to="myShelljob"/>
<error to="myShelljob"/>
```

In error section mentioned next Shell action name and instead of failing. it will continue to next shell action.
In shell action you can check file is exists or not. if file not exists, continue next action and if any other error occurred then action will fail.

Comment: Except that that can't flex on what kind of error it is, can it? I'd only want it to do some other action that's the same action but without the file again if it specifically errored on the file being missing, if it fails for any other reason I wouldn't want it to attempt running without the file.

Comment: @Shufflepants : Please read my updated answer.Basically you need to check whether file exists or not and accordingly decide your action.

Answer (score 0):

Oozie provides User-Retry capabilities when an action is in **ERROR or FAILED state**.

You can specify the **retry-max** and **retry-interval** in the action definition. So, when the file is not in directory it gets retried rather than failing.

Examples of **User-Retry** in a workflow action is :

```
  <workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.3" name="wf-name">
  <action name="a" retry-max="2" retry-interval="1">
  </action>
```

Reference : [User-Retry for Workflow Actions (since Oozie 3.1)](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a18_User-Retry_for_Workflow_Actions_since_Oozie_3.1)

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue. I don't need it to retry to look for the file again, I need it to continue on without it.